# form:error not showing error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When validating object controller just refreshes the page, instead showing errors via form:errors, can you tell me where is the problem. I guest it needs to get error from binding result and insert it into the page, instead controller is just refreshing page

Controller :

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createProduct(MultipartFile image, Model model,@ModelAttribute @Valid ProductDto product, BindingResult bindingResult) throws IOException {
   productValidator.validate(product,bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "admin/create";
    } else {
        return "index";
    }

}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createProduct(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("product", new ProductDto());
    model.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.findAll());
    return "admin/create";
}
```

Validator :

```
    @Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return ProductDto.class.equals(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {

    ProductDto product = (ProductDto) o;

    if (product.getTitle().isEmpty() || product.getTitle() == null) {
        errors.rejectValue("title", "product.title", "Product title cant be empty");
    }
    if (product.getDescription().isEmpty() || product.getDescription() == null) {
        errors.rejectValue("description", "product.description", "Product description cant be empty");
    }
    if (product.getPrice() == null || product.getPrice()<=0) {
        errors.rejectValue("price", "product.price", "Product price is not valid");
    }
    if (product.getCategoryId()==null) {
        errors.rejectValue("category", "product.category", "Product category is not valid");
    }

}
```

jstl page :

```
                            <spring:url value="/product/create" var="formUrl"/>
                        <form:form modelAttribute="product" action="${formUrl }" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Title</label>
                                <form:input id="title"
                                            cssClass="form-control" path="title"/>
                                <form:errors path="title"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Description</label>
                                <form:textarea id="description" rows="10"
                                               cssClass="form-control" path="description"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Price</label>
                                <form:input id="price" type="number"
                                            cssClass="form-control" path="price"/>
                                <form:errors path="description"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="sel1">Select category</label>
                                <form:select id="sel1" cssClass="form-control" path="categoryId">
                                    <form:options items="${categories}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="title"/>
                                </form:select>
                            </div>
                            <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                Image <input type="file" multiple accept='image/*' ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" name="image" style="display: block;">
                            </label>
                            <br><br>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success text-center"><span
                                        class="fa fa-check"></span> Submit
                                </button>
                                <a href="/" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg  text-center"><span
                                        class="fa fa-times"></span> Cancel
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `product` model attribute has different name in your `POST`-handling method.

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html#name--):

> The default model attribute name is inferred from the declared
>   attribute type (i.e. the method parameter type or method return type),
>   based on the non-qualified class name: e.g. "orderAddress" for class
>   "mypackage.OrderAddress", or "orderAddressList" for
>   "List<mypackage.OrderAddress>".

So your `ProductDto product` attribute will have name `productDto` in resulting model. But you referring the `product` in your template.

Try to explicitly set the `name` attribute of `@ModelAttribute` annotation

```
public String createProduct(MultipartFile image, Model model, @ModelAttribute(name = "product") @Valid ProductDto product, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

And to make sure that bidning and validation actually works, try to log it:

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    System.err.println("Form has errors!");
}
```